# Can any one pls help me understand this code and what vulnerabilities exists?

Tags: web-application, web

[image]

what Vulnerabilities exists???

Comment: Welcome to Security SE. We prefer not finding vulnerabilities in some code for you. If you are doing it to learn, please tell us what have you tried so far so that we can guide you in the correct direction

Comment: Welcome to  Stack Exchange! May I give a few pieces of advice? First, when asking questions, show what you have tried yourself. Second, when posting code, post it as text, indented by 4 spaces to get it in `code markdown`. Don't post images of code.

Comment: OK, I understand. I didnt have a clear note as how to post a question. I ll make sure from the next questions.

Answer (score 1):

> Can any one pls help me understand this code

It is a "reset your password" page. If the email exists in the database, then it says it can't reset your password (I'd venture an educated guess the password reset system has been recently abused).

If it does not exist, it says it cannot reset your password (with reason).

Any vulnerabilities still extant would be connected with the fact that the page is echoing back whatever "email" is sent to the page itself (there's no checking that it *is* a valid email), and that the same whatever is used for a, presumably, SQL operation directed to finding whether the email is in the database, or not.

Depending on how this latter operation is done, what access is granted to the database, whether its schema is known, and other factors, all sorts of information might be leaked from the database. Possibly, again depending on the database backend, some potentially harmful instructions might be sent to the database as well, and be executed.

In general, such a password reset scheme would need to be something like:

```
check the request is valid

check the email is valid. If not, say "The email you sent is not valid".

check how many emails match in the database.

say "If the address is in the database, an email will be sent shortly.
     Check your spam folder yadda yadda. If you still don't receive an
     email, that means the email was not in our database: contact us."

close browser connection.
(wait a random amount from 0 to 5 seconds)
check that the "sent email" flag is less than 3 and the "last sent"
is more than 24 hours ago; we don't want to spam third parties.
if the email matches number was equal to 1, send the email and increment
the "sent email" flag by 1, also set "last sent" to the current datetime.
```

Basically whoever requests the password reset:

- **MUST NOT** be able to do anything else (aka "Hello, [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)!").
- **MUST NOT** be told whether he guessed the right email
  (knowing whether someone's email is in Nasty'r'Us user base is a privacy breach even if they can try and say someone else did sign them up)

  - not even indirectly, by timing how long does it take to say "Sorry"
- **MUST NOT** be able to bombard someone with password reset messages

Answer (score 0):

The code appears to take value of the "Email" from the request and directly appended within the tags, when no account is found.